# findViewById for child View

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to get items from a child `View` that is added to the `View` when a `Button`  is clicked. But when I try to get the elements in the created child `View` it returns a `null`.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
```

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonAddPerson"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Another Person"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPeople"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Layout that is added with button click:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:id="@+id/linearLayoutPerson">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/editTextFirstName"
    android:hint="First Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    />
```

```
 public View onCreateView(final LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

     view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_occupants, container, false);
    Button addPersonButton = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonAddPerson);


      root = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutPeople);

    View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_person_layout,null);
    root.addView(child);

   addPersonButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {

         //  createPersonAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           View child = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_person_layout,null);
           root.addView(child);

       }
   });

    return view;
}
```

When I try to get the information:

```
public void  SaveCall(){

   EditText firstName;

    for (int i =1;i<=root.getChildCount();i++){         
        View child = root.getChildAt(i);
//null at this line            
firstName = (EditText) child.findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try like this

Change this `i<=root.getChildCount();` to `i<root.getChildCount();` and start from `i=0;`

```
 for (int i =0;i<root.getChildCount();i++){         
        View child = root.getChildAt(i);
//null at this line            
firstName = (EditText) child.findViewById(R.id.editTextFirstName);

    }
```

Comment: and why would it cause a NPE ?

Comment: If the root.getChildCount() is 4 then try to get the child from 4th. Because there is the 4th position null. So it must be the nullPointer. If i am wrong please tell me.

Comment: "i" must range from 0 to getChildCount() -1. The cause of the crash is likely that you're trying to access 1 position too far and getChildAt() returns null for that invalid position.

Comment: @BladeCoder Yes you are right if we use i<=root.getChildCount(); then need to use i<=root.getChildCount()-1;. But i am using i<root.getChildCount();. So i think it will work. Maybe i am wrong. Please let me if i done any mistake.

Comment: getChildAt() does not throw IndexOutOfBoundsException, it returns null. Check the documentation: "[returns] the view at the specified position or null if the position does not exist within the group". Your loop condition should be: for (int i = 0; i < root.getChildCount; i++) {}

Comment: @Blackbelt. But "child" is not array it is view. Is it leads to IndexOutBoundException ?.

Comment: @BlackBelt Check for yourself if you don't believe me: https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/ViewGroup.java#L5463

Comment: Changing the loop to as suggested worked, not sure what i was thinking having it at i=1. Thanks @Amsheer

Answer (score 0):

As you dynamically create your views, you could add each EditText to an arrayList. Then do your for loop through that list.